Data table A left join data table B. How can I include all colnames of B into the result？
Data table A left join data table B. How can I include all colnames of B into the result？
table_detail_s is :
>table_detail_s<- data.table(table_name = 'dtA',col_name = c("lc","hs","address_type","address_type_mc","hjry"),
           col_name_raw = c("lc","hs","address_type","address_type","hjry")
           )
> table_detail_s
table_name        col_name col_name_raw
       <char>          <char>       <char>
1:        dtA              lc           lc
2:        dtA              hs           hs
3:        dtA    address_type address_type
4:        dtA address_type_mc address_type
5:        dtA            hjry         hjry

table std_mc_col_s is :
>std_mc_col_s <- data.table(table_name_s = 'dtA',col_name_filter = 'address_type')
>std_mc_col_s
   table_name col_name_raw
       <char>       <char>
1:        dtA address_type

Then table_detail_s left join std_mc_cols_s:
> std_mc_col_s[table_detail_s,
+            on = .(table_name_s == table_name ,
+                   col_name_filter == col_name)]
   table_name_s col_name_filter col_name_raw
         <char>          <char>       <char>
1:          dtA              lc           lc
2:          dtA              hs           hs
3:          dtA    address_type address_type
4:          dtA address_type_mc address_type
5:          dtA            hjry         hjry

I am confused that the content of column col_name_filter contains other values ​​besides address_type? In addition, I want to include the table_name_s in column in the result. How should I do this?
Any help I will be very appreciate.

Not sure on your outcome, either you want nomatch=NULL,
> library(data.table)
> std_mc_col_s[table_detail_s, 
+              on=.(table_name_s=table_name , col_name_filter=col_name),
+              nomatch=NULL]
   table_name_s col_name_filter col_name_raw
         <char>          <char>       <char>
1:          dtA    address_type address_type

or you only want to join on table_name_s*.
> std_mc_col_s[table_detail_s, on = .(table_name_s = table_name)]
   table_name_s col_name_filter        col_name col_name_raw
         <char>          <char>          <char>       <char>
1:          dtA    address_type              lc           lc
2:          dtA    address_type              hs           hs
3:          dtA    address_type    address_type address_type
4:          dtA    address_type address_type_mc address_type
5:          dtA    address_type            hjry         hjry

In either case, use = instead of ==.
Edit
To get desired NA where address_type doesn't match, you'd need duplicate the second join column to sth like col_name_new and don't join on it.
> std_mc_col_s[,col_name_new := col_name_filter][table_detail_s, 
+              on=.(table_name_s=table_name , col_name_filter=col_name)]
   table_name_s col_name_filter col_name_new col_name_raw
         <char>          <char>       <char>       <char>
1:          dtA              lc         <NA>           lc
2:          dtA              hs         <NA>           hs
3:          dtA    address_type address_type address_type
4:          dtA address_type_mc         <NA> address_type
5:          dtA            hjry         <NA>         hjry


Data:
> dput(table_detail_s)
structure(list(table_name = c("dtA", "dtA", "dtA", "dtA", "dtA"
), col_name = c("lc", "hs", "address_type", "address_type_mc", 
"hjry"), col_name_raw = c("lc", "hs", "address_type", "address_type", 
"hjry")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x56a304a64c10>)
> dput(std_mc_col_s)
structure(list(table_name_s = "dtA", col_name_filter = "address_type"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x56a304a64c10>)


Lines 1,2,3 and 5 of col_name_filter maye NA,how can i get these result?
